# How to disable the fading effect on window titles in the task manager?

Tags: ubuntu, taskbar, kde

Window titles are automatically faded in the built-in task manager:

[image]

How can I disable this fading effect?

I am using Linux Kubuntu 14.10 Plasma 4.

Comment: I have the same question! How can this be disabled???